# Problems removing listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Here's the function that I'm now struggling with:

```
function close(ubicacion){
return function(){


    if ((event.target.className == 'contCurso') || (event.target.className == 'cerrar') || (window.event.keyCode == 27) ){

        closeWindow('contCurso', ubicacion); //se cierra el curso
        document.removeEventListener('click',close);
        document.removeEventListener('keydown',close);
    }
    else{
        console.log('Listener not removed');  } }}
```

close is being called as a handler from another function like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', close(contCurso));  
document.addEventListener('keydown', close(contCurso));
```

Not only is not removing the listeners I wanted it to, but it is also removing some that I added on the main that were not meant to be removed.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you add `'click', close(contCurso)` ... you remove `'click',close` ... not the same function, is it

Comment: of course, you're adding separate handler for click and keydown, and in each handler you're  trying to remove both handlers - this won't work either - perhaps you need to do something like https://jsfiddle.net/4amx8d72/

Comment: This solves the first problem! But it keeps removing the Listeners that I added in the main code.

Comment: it shouldn't be doing that, what listeners?

Comment: The others listeners look like this:
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkWindow(txtm,txt,link,intro)); 

 link.onclick = changeText(txt,link2); 
 link2.onclick = changeText(txtm,link); 

 for(var i=0; i < cursos.length; i++) {

     cursos[i].onclick = loadCourse; 

 }

Comment: well, your code can not be removing those listeners - what does `closeWindow` do? are those listeners attached to a window that is closed by that function?

Comment: loadCourse is a reference to the function where I call 'close'

Comment: I didn't ask about `loadCourse` at all

Comment: closeWindow() deletes the HTML code that loadCourse adds

Comment: so, any event listeners added to the HTML that loadCourse adds will also be removed - sorry, but the code in the comment is hard to read for a start, so I'm not going to be much help

Comment: Yes indeed, but these listeners that I'm talking about are not being added by  loadCourse. Even when closeWindow is finished and has removed the added HTML, I can see the HTML code that SHOULD had the listeners attached still.

Comment: Let's say I have some 'original HTML' and 'extra HTML' which is added by loadCourse. closeWindow removes only the extra HTML, but the listeners attached to the original HTML are being removed as well (not the HTML though, just the listeners).

Comment: loadCourse has a XMLHttpRequest inside(were a lot of actions take place), and apparently, this line is removing the other listeners:
main.innerHTML += template.response;
The question is why?

Comment: because you are manipulating innerHTML ... don't do that ... try `insertAdjacentHTML` or work with the DOM using methods such as `.appendChild`

Comment: Great, I'll try that out. Could you please tell me why is that not ok?

Comment: because changing innerHTML  in effect creates all new elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `document.addEventListener('click', close(contCurso));` you're evaluating the function `close`, which returns another function that gets attached as the callback for the listener. However, when you try to remove it you're just passing it a reference to the function `close` which is *not* the function that is attached, so nothing gets removed.

If you want to attach an event listener in that way you will have to save a reference to the original function that you attached in order to be able to remove it later:

```
let listener = close(contCurso);
document.addEventListener('click', listener);
...
document.removeEventListener('click', listener);
```

It's not enough even to call `removeEventListener('click', close(contCurso))` because it doesn't return a reference to the same function.

Comment: I'm getting an error from doing this:loadcourse.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: listener is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (loadcourse.js:9)

Comment: But close is executing closeWindow just fine.

Comment: Probably because of where you are defining `listener`. It needs to have higher scope than whatever functions are using it, most likely global.